# How to proxy pass to a certain url depends on the request url by nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have two hello servers in server1(1.1.1.1) and server2(1.1.1.2). Now I want to use Nginx(example.com) to proxy pass request to the certain server like this:

Request Url:http://example.com/hello1
proxy pass:http://1.1.1.1/hello

Reqeust Url:http://example.com/hello2
proxy pass:http://1.1.1.2/hello

Answer (score 0):

Just add the location block to example.com config. This should work.

```
location ^~ /hello1 {
      proxy_set_header Proxy "";
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1/hello;
      proxy_redirect off;
}

location ^~ /hello2 {
      proxy_set_header Proxy "";
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://1.1.1.2/hello;
      proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: It works! It's exactly what I want. Thank you very much! But I don't understand. Why "/hello1" or "/hello2" won't be added to the proxy_pass url just like "http://1.1.1.1/hello/hello1" ?

Comment: If you need the end url to be [http://1.1.1.1/hello/hello1] (http://1.1.1.1/hello/hello1) just add hello1 to the proxy_pass

Comment: Fixing a URI at the end of `proxy_pass` generally isn't a good idea, but yes, that's what you'd do